# What type of FEI should I use?

Tags: redhawksdr

I have a device that has one 40MHz wideband input and can output one wideband output and 8 narrowband DDC channels from a device. I am not sure how to setup the FEI interface for this device. Should it be a CHANNELIZER or an RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER? I am leaning towards the latter due to the wideband output.

Regarding the allocation of such a device. For the RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER types, the manual is vague in the use of the CHANNELIZER portion in this instance. Should I still allow CHANNELIZERS to be allocated or just allocate the RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZERs and DDCs? Should changes to the RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER determine when to drop the DDCs in this instance? If CHANNELIZERS can still be allocated with a RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER, how does this work?

Comment: I have decided to move forward allowing RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER and CHANNELIZER tuners to be allocated. Only RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER will enable the streaming of the wideband output. The CHANNELIZERs will behave exactly the same but without the wideband output. Allocations on the wideband will have to be one or the other but the tuner status will show only RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER. The DDC portion will work the same as specified under the CHANNELIZER in the 2.0.1 manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A channelizer device takes already digitized data and provides DDCs from this digital stream. A RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER has a analog input and performs the receiver, digitizer and channelizer function in a non-separable device. It sounds like you choose correctly to use the RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER for a device with an analog input. Typically allocating the RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZER takes care of allocating the Channelizer because all three parts are linked together. Therefore the only additional allocations are usually DDCs.